# REST Service with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: java, database, mongodb, rest

Ive tried to create a REST Service with MongoAtlas but get a 404 not Found Exception.

I have the following folder structure

```
com.example.demo3
                 Demo3Application.java
                 CRUDEMongo.java
                |_test
                      CrudeController.java
```

```
package com.example.demo3;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerApi;
import com.mongodb.ServerApiVersion;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo3", "com.example.demo3.test"})
public class Demo3Application{
    @Autowired
    Test test;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
        String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://torben:<password>@cluster0.orswsxw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
        ServerApi serverApi = ServerApi.builder().version(ServerApiVersion.V1).build();
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString)).serverApi(serverApi).build();
        System.out.println("Hello");
        try(MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings)){
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.demo3;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
@EnableMongoRepositories
public interface CRUDEMongo extends CrudRepository<Test, Test>{

}
```

```
package com.example.demo3.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CrudeController {
  @RequestMapping(value="/te", method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public String requestMethodName() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

Everytime I try to connect with URL/te on Postman I get a 404 not found Exception. Spring doesn't seem to found my RestController. I tried everthing. Change folders, ComponentScan but it doesn't seem to find it.

Tried to set up a REST Service with Spring but get a 404 not found Exception via Postman. Im definitly connected with the database because I get the following back:

```
MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync", "version": "4.9.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.15.0-78-generic"}, "platform": "Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.7+7"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=majority, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='torben', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@5cff6b74, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@627ff1b8]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=cluster0.orswsxw.mongodb.net, srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-12upi3-shard-0', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=ServerApi{version=V1, deprecationErrors=null, strict=null}, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

Comment: Can you comment the line RequestMapping("/") and try again

Comment: Tried it again with "https://eu-central-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-kvswz/endpoint/data/v1/te" but nothing changed

Comment: Not able to open the link.

Comment: Being able to open the link is not important because you would just get a 404 Not Found Exception for your request. I just took the URL given by MongoDB Atlas and added "/te" for the request. It didnt work out.

Comment: It has nothing to do with mongo. Your Rest endpoint is not working. Share your properties file too.

Comment: I didnt know that I had to write something in my properties. My application.propertie is empty

Comment: What is the url your using? localhost:8080/te?

Comment: String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://torben:<password>@cluster0.orswsxw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"; Thats the connection String I use. Since I do erverything over MongosAtlas with AWS

Comment: I doubt this is causing the 404 as mentioned earlier in the comments - but separately this certainly looks suspicious/wrong if it is your intent to connect to a cloud service as opposed to a local database: `clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017]`

Comment: i also thought that this looked wrong but I connected with the code Atlas produced by atlas for their connection.